# QGIS Server GetMap WIDTH Parameter

Tags: python, qgis-server

I have a working QGIS-Server in one of my Docker container. If i use a display with a high resolution (beyond 2000px in width), QGIS-Server is splitting the request into two Requests. The first request with a WIDTH of 2000 and a second request with the rest. This behavior sabotage my use case. I found the setting `<WMSMaxWidth type="int"> </WMSMaxWidth>`, which i have set to 3000. Unfortunately the result is the same.

Can someone give me a hint or a concrete solution to increase the value in WIDTH, so that everything can be processed with only one WMS GetMap request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. The problem is not that the qgis server can't handle requests beyond 2000px width. My QGIS desktop is not able to send dynamical a bigger request. I have to set manualy the tile size to something higher than 2000px.